# Conveying to manager about bereavement affected work

Tags: communication, project-management

Over the weekend I was supposed to give an important last piece of work that was on me, but while working I got news of my dad's sister passing away and I couldn't believe it. It impacted daily life and work including that which I told our CTO will be done by weekend.
Now she is upset, which she expressed in a message last night.

How can I tell my manager about the situation and also that my system is already very slow and become unresponsive (which sounds like I am making an excuse)?

Comment: The death is clearly not an excuse, so why haven't you said just that? Though the system added on top that does get into excuse-y territory, if it's actually an issue with getting work done timely, why haven't you raised it before?

Comment: Presumably you knew your system was slow when you made your estimate, so why bring it up now?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I did not made estimate and I came to know 1 week after when CTO causally mentioned in the chat, and she was shocked, the slow system had been on and off issue. I would have probably completed it if I didn't had news of my aunty death

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul read my comment above this one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I'm sorry for your loss. Now to the question:

> how can I tell my manager about sitaution

It doesn't need to be more than an email to your boss in more or less the form of: "Hey Xyz, I had a death in the family this very weekend and it's taken a toll on me. I don't think I can reliably finish my current work commitments for at least next few days. I wanted to let you know sooner, but honestly this is first moment I actually thought about work since, it was all so sudden.".

And that's about all there is to the matter, death happens and everyone should understand that all people grieve differently. Sometimes it's timed poorly, but that's life, or rather death which is not known to check the calendars for convenient time before happening. If the manager doesn't respond well that's another question to open.

> and also that my system is already very slow and become unresponsive which sounding it like I am making excuse?

Don't mention that as it doesn't matter. Time to raise this was before you took on the task, but then as you clarified within the comments it's not really enough of an issue, and you were going to deliver despite it. So don't try to make it an issue now, there's nothing to be gained from it.

Comment: Another Problem here is I do not know bereavement policy so I might be shooting in dark asking for days off where I cannot do it coz she is an aunt etc.

Comment: @localhost let your boss figure that out, no one sane expects someone in grief to pour over employee handbook

Answer (score 1):

"I have had an unexpected Death in the family and will be taking time off to deal with this. I will inform you when I will be returning"

Death isn't negotiable. Death isn't planned. This is one of those times to draw a very hard and very clear line in the sand with the words 'Work/Life Balance' on either side.

Your CTO can get pissy about missed deadlines till the cows come home to roost, I doubt she'd be attending **your** funeral. But your family will.

If your CTO doesn't understand, then it's time to look for a new job with a non-toxic manager.

Don't get me wrong, a sudden unexpected absence sucks and a Manager can get grumpy about having to re-jig everything - that's human. But they should also understand that it's life and death and there's nothing they can do about it.

Take the time off, be with your family, grieve for your Aunt (my condolences for your loss) and then when ready, head back into work.